# How to reduce first time byte via code optimization?

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization

I understand, first time byte is a tricky subject since it depends on lot of factors.I am trying to optimize the code as much as I can for this [site](http://www.singhcycle.com)
This site is on a shared hosting hence, I am not excepting top notch performance, however still I am trying squeeze every single precious ms that I can .

This is my profile [output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GL1R_GxX0C-vVeiafQgigUGvZYUE5HWOFq7VoINADBs/edit?usp=sharing)

Could anybody tell me if the execution times on Banner7(Home Page Slider) is good enough? The slider takes some to load. Is the Banner7 is a bottleneck. What could be the other areas of opportunity to optimize?
Here's the result from [Webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160203_37_7D7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shared hosting is not the place for optimization if you dont have access to webstack settings.
the only option you have is - full page cache. LestiFPC
https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc

C'est la vie.

Comment: I am slightly apprehensive about this extension. What does it mean by full cache? Ain't I already caching most of my static connect? Do I really need this extra plugin?

Comment: you have to use Full Page Cache to avoid php processing every time and minimize database load...

Comment: I don't see LestiFPC in Magento  Connect. How can i install it?

Comment: https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc